# How do I pass an object to a component?

Tags: ember.js

This question was asked in the [Ember Discord](https://discord.gg/emberjs).

> Is there a way to pass an object into a component

```
<SomeComponent object={color: green} />
```

Answer (score 4):

*Using latest Ember from October of 2021*

yes! two ways,

via template-only:

```
<SomeComponent @object={{hash color="green"}} />
```

This uses the [hash](https://api.emberjs.com/ember/3.28/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/hash?anchor=hash) helper.

Note that there are other differences here as well.
Arguments must begin with `@` (to differentiate from *attributes*), which are native HTML, such as `class`, `id`, etc -- and "dynamic bits" in ember are surrounded by double curlies, `{{}}`. For an overview of attributes and arguments, I recommend [Component Arguments and HTML Attributes](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/component-arguments-and-html-attributes/) from the official guides.

The second way to pass an object to a component is if you already have one:

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
  myObject = { color: 'green' };
}
```

```
<SomeComponent @object={{this.myObject}} />
```